# [Delphi] Подсчёт строк из файла, прогресс бар.

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, никак не разберусь как подсчитать строки из файла который грузится в мемо, а сам момент подгрузки отображается в прогресс баре.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('acc.txt');
end;

procedure TForm1.Label1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.lines.LoadFromFile('acc.txt');
end;

end.
```

Comment: А что, файл, на самом деле такой большой, что ещё и момент загрузки отображать надо (такстовый, как правило, грузится быстро)?

Comment: Я боюсь, что так сделать и не получится. К тому же в процессе загрузки лучше, наверное, апдейт элемента Memo отключить. К тому же лучше разбить процесс на этапы. Я бы, наверное, сначала грузил файл во временный буфер. Хотя бы TStringList, при этом рисую прогресс-бар, а затем уже связывал список строк с Memo

Comment: Два момента:

* если вы грузить столь большой файл в память, что нужен прогрессбар, возможно вы что-то делаете неправильно.
* если файл маленький, то прогрессбар и не нужен.

исходя из этого, задачу опишите подробнее.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, полностью согласен! Даже, если файл весит 15КБ, что очень немало, то он загрузится за 1-3 секунды.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно так
Возможно будет медленее чем lines.LoadFromFile но зато есть информация до какой строки файла дошли.

```
procedureTForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Varf:TextFile; // объявление файловой переменной
st:String; // строковая переменная
istr:integer;//номер строки
begin
AssignFile(f,'c:\acc.txt'); // привязка названия файла к файловой переменной
{$I-} // отключение контроля ошибок ввода-вывода
Reset(f); // открытие файла для чтения
{$I+} // включение контроля ошибок ввода-вывода
ifIOResult<>0 then // если есть ошибка открытия, то
begin
ShowMessage('Ошибка открытия файла C:\1.TXT');
Exit; // выход из процедуры при ошибке открытия файла
end;

istr:=0;
While not EOF(f) do // пока не конец файла делать цикл:
begin
ReadLn(f,st); // читать из файла строку
Memo1.Lines.add (st);

//ну а тут можно показать какая строка уже прочитанна
// например так
inc(istr);
label1.caption=inttostr(istr)
end;

CloseFile(f); // закрыть файл

end;
```

Если времени не жалко можно для начала пройтись циклом

```
While not EOF(f) do // пока не конец файла делать цикл:
begin
  ReadLn(f);
  inc(istr);
end;
```

узнать количество строк istr а потом уже показать все это в прогресе.

Answer (score 0):

Количество строк в компоненте TMemo можно получить так:

```
 Memo1.Lines.Count;
```